# Tkkinter issue with checkboxes and tk.Text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

hope you are doing great.

i have a list of numbers:

```
functions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and that list is dinamically assign to checkboxes:

```
checkbox_values = [tk.BooleanVar() for _ in range(len(functions))]
for i, option in enumerate(functions):
    #colCount = i % 1
    rowCount = i % 6
    colCount = (i // 6) # Determine which column this checkbox should be in

    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=option, variable=checkbox_values[i])
    checkbox.grid(row=rowCount + 3, column=colCount, padx=10, sticky="w")
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMDgI.png)

Then i need a tk.Text with a dinamic width base on the total columns of the checkbox, so im adding this:

```
output_window = tk.Text(root, width=60, height=20)
output_window.grid(row=len(functions) + 1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
```

this is the result

[checkboxes are moved here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yCq2.png)

as ypu can see for some reason the checkboxes separates and i dont want that.

this is the full code im using:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cisco Device Commands")

#  checkbox
functions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

checkbox_values = [tk.BooleanVar() for _ in range(len(functions))]
for i, option in enumerate(functions):
    #colCount = i % 1
    rowCount = i % 6
    colCount = (i // 6) # Determine which column this checkbox should be in

    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=option, variable=checkbox_values[i])
    checkbox.grid(row=rowCount + 3, column=colCount, padx=10, sticky="w")
    print(rowCount, colCount)

output_window = tk.Text(root, width=60, height=20)
output_window.grid(row=len(functions) + 1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
# Start the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

any ideas??

i want checkboxes dont separate as i add tk.Entry

Comment: Might try using .place instead of .grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the text widget a size of 60, so that's the size grid will try to preserve. That's wider than the checkbuttons so it forces the two columns to grow so that the text widget will fit.

A simple solution is to add an additional column to the right of the checkbuttons to fill any extra space. OR, put the checkbuttons in a frame so that they can be laid out independently from the text widget.

Here's an example of using a frame for the checkbuttons. `pack` is used for the frame and the text widget for simplicity, then `grid` is used to layout the checkbuttons inside the frame.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cisco Device Commands")

checkbutton_frame = tk.Frame(root)
output_window = tk.Text(root, width=60, height=20)

checkbutton_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
output_window.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

#  checkbox
functions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


checkbox_values = [tk.BooleanVar() for _ in range(len(functions))]
for i, option in enumerate(functions):
    #colCount = i % 1
    rowCount = i % 6
    colCount = (i // 6) # Determine which column this checkbox should be in

    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text=option, variable=checkbox_values[i])
    checkbox.grid(row=rowCount + 3, column=colCount, padx=10, sticky="w")
    print(rowCount, colCount)

# Start the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]